The recharts library draws the Y axis incorrectly
The recharts library draws the Y axis incorrectly
enter image description here
code
    <YAxis
          type="number"
          dataKey="response"
          name="Response"
          tickFormatter={(v) => String(safeRound(v, 2))}
          interval={0}
          domain={["0", 'auto']}
        />

I set the minimum value to 0. But it still takes -1500 from somewhere. Even though there are no such numbers in the data I'm passing in
I set the minimum domain=[0, 'auto']

Would be helpful if you could provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Also, it seems you set the "0" in the domain as a string instead of a number. Try to change that and see if it helps

+1. You need to use numbers to indicate domain in a numeric axis. "auto" is fine since its a reserved word by recharts, but "0" will be treated like a category
